# Loading content from expression engine theme using jQuery

Tags: jquery, expressionengine

I have created my static theme with html, css and JavaScript, I'm using ajax to load dontent to different parts of page, when I bring to expression engine, I want external content to be loaded from a template page that I made, So for example in index.php, I want content to be loaded from:

```
index.php/page
```

in JavaScript:

```
$("#somediv").load('index.php/page');
```

but this doesn't work.
Any ideas would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: More information needed about your problem. Do you get any errors in your browser developer console ? Is jQuery included on the page ?

Comment: is there any content when you access index.php/page via your browser?

Comment: @darshanags Yes the content is there

Comment: @soderslatt No, There is no error, and yes, jquery is loaded.

Comment: and .load() returns a http 200 response and not an 404/500 response? Does somediv id exist in DOM?

Comment: @Sonyflat need more context or better - an example of the problem you are facing

Comment: @soderslatt Yes, I have a working website outside EE, everything is on it's place, There must be something with the way EE handles the path I guess. I've also tried using full path (http://website.com/index.php/page) but no luck

Comment: As darshanags pointed out, it almost impossible to help you without more information about your problem/context. Please provide an example or a more detailed problem-description

Comment: On a side note, there is now an ExpressionEngine SE site (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com). This question isn't appropriate since it seems more JS focused, but if you have a more specific EE question, we can help you there.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl Thank you very much for pointing that out, I have no Idea where the problem come from, but since I got it working as a static html, I think there must be something with EE's path to page (index.php/page) ,I'll try to find a way to change it to something like : example.com/page.php, This should work i guess.

Comment: You should have any issues pulling using that URL. If it loads by itself in your browser window, it should load fine with load(). Seems like something else is going on.